# tensorflow only support image dimension of 300x300?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I want to ask is tensorflowlite input image only support 300 x 300?
so, aside from 300x300 input image any other input won't be recognize by tensorflowlite>?

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

No, there's no 300x300 limit on Tensorflow-Lite :)

Tensorflow-Lite supports any image dimension you want - you'll likely be limited by you're platform's HW then by the TFL libraries.

Here's an [example from TFL](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android):

```
inputImageBuffer = loadImage(bitmap, sensorOrientation);
tflite.run(inputImageBuffer.getBuffer(), outputProbabilityBuffer.getBuffer().rewind());
```

Here, the "input image" is Android's `bitmap` you see in `loadImage`.
That bitmap is an image which can be configured in pre-processing, but is definitely not limited to 300x300.

## More info

In Tensorflow-Lite (TFL), the inference (the instance to which you give the input, and from which you receive an output) uses byte-buffers to perform.

I think when you ask about image dimensions, you're referring to the idea of a byte-buffer called `TensorImage`.

When creating you're model, and setting an input parameter as "an image", you're also creating meta-data, containing the image height, and width.

You may use TFL libraries to get image dimension from the model, so in this case you're limited by your model.

For more information and example code I suggest you look at the following:

- For running instances with TFL: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference
- For code examples: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples
- For support library (which you can also use to interact with image dimensions): https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/experimental/support/java/README.md